# How to convert image as bytes stream in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to send image as bytes stream to service?

By using belowcode i am binding the Url as image to image control.how to send it as bytes stream again to service?
please help me...
`enter code here`

```
string userimage="http://{ipadress}/sample.jpg";
                        Uri uri = new Uri(userImage, UriKind.Absolute);
                        image2.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload image wp7 serverside.?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10832556/50447)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert above image to a bytearray you can try:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
image2.Source.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
```

EDIT:

If the above code doesn't give the desired results you can try:

```
WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapSource)image2.Source);
byte[] byteArray;

using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream()) {

    bmp.SaveJpeg(stream, bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);

    byteArray = stream.ToArray();
}
```

You need to include the `Microsoft.Phone` namespace for `SaveJpeg` to work.

Comment: Getting Error in below line.image2.Source.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);save method does not contain.

Comment: i didn't find the dll system.drawing.imaging in WP7

Comment: I revised my original answer with a extra example to try